# Floating-point division on AT&T

Tags: assembly

I have a program and there I should calculate the average value
For that, I'll need to divide sum to n
But they are integers and I want the result in floating-point
How can I do it in at&t syntax

Let's say

```
.data
    Sum: .quad 2212
    N:      .quad 20
```

Now how should I declare avg and do the calculation

```
         .global _start
     .data
    message: .string "Elements of the list: \n"
    message1: .string "Sum of elements in the list= %d \n"
    message2: .string "Average of elements in the list= %lf \n"
    message3: .string "Key %d is found at location %d in the list\n"
    message4: .string "Key occurs %d times in the list \n"
    formatd: .string "%ld\n"
    buf: .skip 1024
    a: .float 5.0
    b: .float 2.0
    sum: .quad 0
    avg: .double 0
    key: .quad 32
    N: .quad 20
    count: .quad 0
    list:   .quad 12
            .quad 23
            .quad 32
            .quad 84
            .quad 121
            .quad 34
            .quad 23
            .quad 32
            .quad 93
            .quad 22
            .quad 56
            .quad 32
            .quad 949
            .quad 123
            .quad 99
            .quad 23
            .quad 32
            .quad 289
            .quad 99
            .quad 34
```

this is an array and i am traversing through it and finding the sum and average also i am searching for the key

```
       .text
    _start:
    movq $1, %rax           
    movq $1, %rdi
    movq $message, %rsi
    movq $24, %rdx
    syscall

    xorq %rcx, %rcx
    loop:
    pushq %rax
    pushq %rbx
    pushq %rcx
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $formatd, %rdi  
    movq $list, %rbx
    movq (%rbx,%rcx,8), %rsi
    addq %rsi, sum
    call printf
    popq  %rcx
    popq  %rbx
    popq  %rax

    inc %rcx
    cmp $20,%rcx
    jl loop



    pushq %rax
    pushq %rbx
    pushq %rcx
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $message1, %rdi  
    movq sum, %rsi
    call printf
    popq  %rcx
    popq  %rbx
    popq  %rax
```

up to here i am calculating the sum and displaying each element

```
    #here i want to find avg
    #

    pushq %rax
    pushq %rbx
    pushq %rcx
    movq $0, %rax
    movq $message2, %rdi  
    movq  avg, %rsi
    call printf
    popq  %rcx
    popq  %rbx
    popq  %rax
```

here i want to find the average and display it

Comment: First convert from integer to floating point, and then divide?

Comment: @Sneftel can you show me how to do it I can't find it anywhere

Comment: What architecture are you programming for? If x86, are you using the x87 or the SSE floating point unit?

Comment: Almost a duplicate: [x86-64 Arrays Inputting and Printing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26900835/x86-64-arrays-inputting-and-printing) shows how to printf a double, and does mention the alignment issue, but it's using `main` where the initial alignment is different.  And this question is really asking about division.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me asume that you are programming in long mode.  If you are using the x87 floating point unit, the general approach looks like this:

```
fildq sum(%rip)  # load sum
fildq N(%rip)    # load N
fdivrp           # divide sum by N and pop
```

The result will be in `%st(0)`.  If `N` is a 32 bit integer, you can instead do this:

```
fildq sum(%rip)  # load sum
fidivl N(%rip)   # divide by integer sum
```

If you are using the SSE floating point unit, the code looks like this instead:

```
cvtsi2sdq sum(%rip),%xmm0 # load sum
cvtsi2sdq N(%rip),%xmm1   # load N
divsd     %xmm1,%xmm0     # divide sum by N
```

The result is located in `xmm0`.

Comment: thank you for replying i think third one should work here i updated the question can you have a look i can't make it work by my self

Comment: @FarrukhTulkunov I think I have provided everything you need.  What part are you stuck at?

Comment: @FarrukhTulkunov: Yes, on x86-64 you should normally use SSE / SSE2, only x87 if you specifically need 80-bit `long double`.  And BTW, you don't have to go through memory; you can `cvtsi2sd  %rax, %xmm0` (unlike with x87).  Also, you don't need to keep `sum` in memory; keep it in a call-preserved register like `r12` or `rbx`.

Comment: @PeterCordes @fuz The thing is I can't get it back from `%xmm0` I don't know what I'm doing wrong the old good friend segmentation fault is popping up what should I do after `divsd` to put the result into `%rsi` then to call `printf`

Comment: @FarrukhTulkunov: `printf("%f\n", double_value)` will print a `double` from `%xmm0`.  You have to set `al=1` to tell printf that you passed 1 FP value in registers (because printf is a var-args function).  If you wanted to convert back to integer with rounding or truncation, use `cvtsd2si %xmm0, %rsi` or `cvttsd2si %xmm0, %rsi` (note the extra `t` for truncate toward zero, like a C cast instead of round-to-nearest).  **Before calling `printf`, the stack needs to be aligned by 16**, because printf uses `movaps` to store `xmm0..7` to the stack when `al != 0`.

Comment: @FarrukhTulkunov: so remove your push/pop and use different registers, instead of saving/restoring registers that will be clobbered by printf.  At `_start`, `rsp` is 16-byte aligned, as guaranteed by the ABI.